# error shows on using && operator in chrome snippets

Tags: javascript

```js
prompt("Enter your name");

var lifeExpectancy = Math.random() ;
lifeExpectancy = Math.floor(lifeExpectancy * 100) +  30;
// if (lifeExpectancy > 100){alert(lifeExpectancy + " Years, as old as Dinosaurs")}
if (lifeExpectancy   <= 100 && > 75 ){
alert(lifeExpectancy + " Years , Many more birthdays to come !!!")
} else{
    alert(lifeExpectancy + " Years.")
}
```

Shows error on using && and <= operators

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to mention the name of variable again for the second comaprison

```js
prompt("Enter your name");

var lifeExpectancy = Math.random() ;
lifeExpectancy = Math.floor(lifeExpectancy * 100) +  30;
if (lifeExpectancy   <= 100 && lifeExpectancy > 75 ){
    alert(lifeExpectancy + " Years , Many more birthdays to come !!!")
} else{
    alert(lifeExpectancy + " Years.")
}
```